# Is it possible to have multiple pop-ups present at the same time using the JOptionPane in java?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I want to create a program that displays multiple pop ups at the same time in different locations.

This program creates on pop up shifted to the right and one jFrame shifted to the left.

I want both frames to be pop ups.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class jFrame{
    public static void createWindow(){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocation(100,500);

        frame2.setVisible(true);
        frame2.setLocation(900,500);

        int x = 0;
        int y = 5;
        while(y>x){
          int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Do you wanna get rid of this popup?", "Message", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
          if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Sike \n You thought", "Message", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
          }      
          int reply2 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame2, "Do you wanna get rid of this popup?", "Message", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
          if (reply2 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame2, "Sike \n You thought", "Message", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
          }
        }
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args){
        createWindow()
    }
}
```

Comment: Within the context of a single JVM, with your current approach, no. The `JOptionPane` will block until it's dismissed.  It will also prevent interaction with any other UI element within the context of the JVM. Without playing around with it, it "might" be possible to change the modility of a `JDialog` to allow it to block only it's owner

Answer (score 2):

Start by taking a look at [How to Use Modality in Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html)

Basically, the default modality of the dialog (when `setModal` is `true`) is to block all top level containers.  You can control this by chaning the `ModalityType` of the dialog, for example

[image: Dialogs]

```
import java.awt.Dialog;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class DialogTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DialogTest();
    }

    public DialogTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
                GraphicsDevice device = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
                GraphicsConfiguration gc = device.getDefaultConfiguration();
                Rectangle bounds = gc.getBounds();
                Insets insets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(gc);

                bounds.x += insets.left;
                bounds.y += insets.top;
                bounds.width -= (insets.left + insets.right);
                bounds.height -= (insets.top + insets.bottom);


                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocation(bounds.x + ((bounds.width / 2) - frame.getWidth()),
                        bounds.y + ((bounds.height / 2) - frame.getHeight()));
                frame.setVisible(true);

                JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame2.add(new TestPane());
                frame2.pack();
                frame2.setLocation(bounds.x + ((bounds.width / 2)),
                        bounds.y + ((bounds.height / 2) - frame2.getHeight()));
                frame2.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JButton popup = new JButton("Popup");
            add(popup);

            popup.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JDialog dialog = new JDialog(SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(TestPane.this));
                    dialog.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);

                    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                    gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
                    panel.add(new JLabel("I'll be your dialog today"), gbc);
                    JButton close = new JButton("Close");
                    close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(close).dispose();
                        }
                    });
                    panel.add(close, gbc);
                    dialog.add(panel);
                    dialog.pack();
                    dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(TestPane.this);
                    dialog.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Now, before you ask about getting `JOptionPane` to work this way, the answer is basically, no.

You "can" make a custom extension to `JOptionPane`, which overrides the two `createDialog` methods, but you won't be able to use the `static` helper methods, as they create an instance of `JOptionPane`

Answer (score 0):

yes Of Course It is, 
the only way is :

lets imagine that we have One Panel : myPanel

in myPanel we have one button btn1

in btn1's eventListner we have a method that display a JOptionPan pop1 where we 
have an another button btn2

we can have inside btn2's eventListner that display also an other JOptionPan pop2.

So it is possible.
And you can add customized JOptionPans By the way.